# Is Leviticus 24 13-23 in contradiction with new testament?

Tags: matthew, contradiction, law, leviticus

I hope you can help me out with this dilemma.
In Leviticus 24 (https://www.catholic.org/bible/book.php?id=3...)
God says to Moses the following (V16):

> Whoever blasphemes the name of the LORD must surely be put to death;
> the whole assembly must surely stone him, whether he is a foreign
> resident or native; if he blasphemes the Name, he must be put to
> death.

This sounds to me quite the opposite of what Jesus teaches in the Gospel. If Jesus is God, isn't Leviticus 24 13-23 contradicting the new testament?
How can the same God first being *pro death penalty* and then *forgive your enemy*? It can't be both for sure, otherwise anything is valid.

Here are the verses which contradict Leviticus 24:

> Mathew 5:
> 38 “You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye, and
> tooth for tooth.’[a] 39 But I tell you, do not resist an evil person.
> If anyone slaps you on the right cheek, turn to them the other cheek
> also. 40 And if anyone wants to sue you and take your shirt, hand over
> your coat as well. 41 If anyone forces you to go one mile, go with
> them two miles. 42 Give to the one who asks you, and do not turn away
> from the one who wants to borrow from you.

Note: I do not see any other interpretation here but the historical one since God is commanding all of this to a supposedly historical figure like Moses.

Comment: You should edit the question to explain your thinking because it's very unclear. Governments are allowed to do things that individuals can't.

Comment: Saying that "this contradicts the new testament" is vague and encourages poor answers. Which specific verses in the New Testament do you believe contradict Lev 24.13-23? Then there can be exegesis of these two sets of verses.

Comment: @FedericoGentile says "*That is not what they teach at Mass.*". Even if that's the case, it is irrelevant in this site.  Questions about specific denominational doctrines and teachings should be asked in Christianity.SE.  Here you would need to give explicit scriptures that appear to contradict each other, independent of doctrinal interpretation.

Comment: None of those NT verses seem particularly relevant, except for the ones from Romans 13, which is ironic considering what Romans 13:4-6 says. It would be good if you could focus just on one NT verse that is more obviously in tension with Lev 24. I really expected you to quote the NT verses about loving/forgiving your enemies!

Answer (score 1):

But these scriptures aren't contradictory.

In today's secular world, the law says that:

- The civil authority must put criminals in jail.
- Confining another person is a crime.

That is not a contradiction.
The first is a directive to the judicial system and the second to the general public.

An ordinary citizen is not allowed to lock up someone just because they know they committed a crime.

The Leviticus quotation is for government authorities, while Matthew's is for ordinary people.
There is no conflict or contraction here.

Christians are to follow Jesus's commands to "*forgive those that sin against us*".

But they are also to respect civil authority.
As Romans 13:1–3 says:

> Everyone is to obey the governing authorities, because there is no authority except from God and so whatever authorities exist have been appointed by God.
>
> So anyone who disobeys an authority is rebelling against God's ordinance; and rebels must expect to receive the condemnation they deserve.
>
> Magistrates bring fear not to those who do good, but to those who do evil. So if you want to live with no fear of authority, live honestly and you will have its approval;

Comment: So according to your logic if a Government tells his citizens to kill those who are blasphemous it's all right?

Comment: @FedericoGentile, no, it's not all right. A Christian should submit to civil authority only as far as it doesn't conflict with God's commandments, which obviously have higher priority. If the government says to pay taxes and to drive on one specific side of the road, a Christian will pay taxes and drive accordingly. If the government says to commit murder or worship an idol, a Christian will refuse, and suffer whatever penalty the government assigns.

Comment: From Leviticus: "15 Say to the Israelites: ‘Anyone who curses their God will be held responsible; 16 anyone who blasphemes the name of the Lord is to be put to death. The entire assembly must stone them. Whether foreigner or native-born, when they blaspheme the Name they are to be put to death."
Assume a movement applies what is written there. How do you respond in that case?
The example you make about taxes does not fit in this case since they are not intrinsically wrong.

Comment: so? how do you reply to my comment?

Comment: @FedericoGentile, I don't understand your confusion.
As you said: "16 *anyone who blasphemes the name of the Lord is to be put to death.*",
but the very next verse says: "17 *Anyone who strikes down any other human being will be put to death.*".
¶The "put to death" is obviously what's required by the civil authorities, not by individual citizens.
If it weren't so, verse 17 would mean that everyone in the nation must take turns killing each other until there is no one left.
…

Comment: @FedericoGentile, … If tomorrow, the law (in say Czechia or Canada) were changed so that capital punishment must be administered by a randomly chosen citizen, you or I could choose to refuse that duty and suffer the legal consequences.
Christians must follow the laws of the ruling government, but not if it would mean breaking a Christian law.
That might be a dilemma, but it's not a contradiction.

Comment: Butterworh But from what i understand putting down to death a person who is blaspheme or who has murdered someone it is indeed a Christian law: it is written in Leviticus 24 and commended by God so in theory a Christian should follow those laws. So not only it is a dilemma but in contradiction with Christ's teaching "love your neighbor as yourself". Who in his right mind would love to be killed?

Comment: @FedericoGentile, those blasphemy laws were intended specifically for the government of the Israelite nation, which hasn't existed for over two thousand years, long before Christianity even existed. Christians, then and now, are subject to the laws of whatever nation they happen to live in. It is not a Christian's duty, or right, to enforce laws on the behaviour of other people. That's what governments are for.

Comment: thanks for your answer and patience. I think your comment makes sense for one side but it raises in me many other objections. I hope I didn't come out as rude and if I did I apologies. My intent is just to dig down to the understand even the minimal of details.

Comment: Jesus taught we are to forgive those who harm us.  But in today's society someone who harmed us in some way can end up getting arrested, charged and convicted and punished for a crime.  At that point, the crime is against the State, as in, "The State vs. John Doe".  That doesn't change the fact that we forgave the person who harmed us, it's simply what the State has to do to maintain order.  God says He won't forgive us unless we forgive our enemies, so we have no choice in that respect.  But the criminal must still be punished;  it's just not us who is doing the punishing.

Answer (score 0):

Leviticus can’t be compared with the gospel as presented by Paul in the New Testament. Paul’s Gospel was one of Grace and Mercy. Leviticus was outlining the Law. There is no Grace, nor Mercy under the Law. Moses was warned (after the Law came) by the Angel that would lead the Israelites that there would be zero tolerance.

**EXODUS 23:21** *Beware of Him and obey His voice; do not provoke Him, for He will not pardon your transgressions;*

Different covenants, completely different. The Levitical Law required man to ‘be good’ (righteous). The new covenant doesn’t - just as well, because man couldn’t. So, no contradiction - as each covenant had a different ‘foundation.  So it’s not a matter of God changing. Man (specifically the Israelites) asked for that covenant. It was not Gods idea, it came about as a result of a ‘stiff necked’ people.

This ‘apparent’ death penalty was not Gods idea, nor intent. It was the penalty for violating the Law, any Law, not just the ‘blasphemy’ you quoted. The death penalty was demanded by the Law. That’s why (one of the reasons) Jesus came (had to come), to free the Jews from the hold that the Law had on them.

Comment: Saying there was no grace or mercy in the law is a big overstatement.

Comment: @curiousdannii overstatement? I quoted a verse saying there would be zero tolerance. Where was the Grace or Mercy for the man stoned to death for Picking up Sticks on the Sabbath? Deserts get cold at night. Even Jesus in the New Testament couldn’t exercise any Mercy for anyone under the Law.

Comment: All of the sacrifices and the forgiveness God offers is part of the grace and mercy in the Law.

Comment: @curiousdannii The sacrifices were instigated after, or outside of the Law. As were the ceremonies, example, Yom Kippur came after that man was stoned to death, (actually because he was stoned - without any way ‘out’.). But - importantly - the sacrifices did *not* provide forgiveness. They provided ‘cover’. They ‘covered’ the ‘sin’ from the Law, in effect so that the Law could not ‘see’ them (because there is no mercy nor grace under the Law)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't make sense: if god and jesus are the same person they cannot command contradictory things.

Comment: Furthermore I always understood that you must read the old testament from the point of view of the new testament. By doing so, paradoxes arise.

Comment: Paul changes the Law - Jesus followed the Laws - Exodus 20:7 “You shall not misuse the name of the Lord your God, for the Lord will not hold anyone guiltless who misuses his name(NIV). Acts 13:39 "Through him everyone who believes is set free from every sin, a justification you were not able to obtain under the law of Moses"(NIV). Many examples in the bible.

Comment: @Federico Gentile please show me where, or how you think I’m having Jesus and God contradict each other in my outline? I accept my answer won’t make sense (to you) at first, else you wouldn’t have asked the question. Do you accept that there are two covenants? One based on the Law? And the ‘new’ covenant based on what Jesus did?

Comment: @another theory ‪1 You are ‬absolutely right. Jesus followed the Law, to the letter. He was born a Jew, under that covenant of the Law. He had to, in order to fulfill it. And he had to fulfill it to get the Jews out from under it. But, on the second point ‘Paul changed the Law’, you are incorrect. He was only a man. In fact, no one has changed it. No one. No one can. Its still exactly the same. The only difference is that it’s been fulfilled.

Comment: @Dave I accept there are 2 covenants. It doesn't make sense that one condones murder and the other forbidden it. Especially if they come from the same person (assuming that you believe that God and Jesus are the same person). I mean, during my researches I found some answers which are definitely more logical then the "ones" proposed here but still not enough that is why I want to have more points of view.

Comment: @Federico Gentile I understand your question. I had similar. God did not ‘condone’ death - at all! And, God is the same, in both Testaments - a loving God of Grace and Mercy. The traditional ‘view’ of the Old Testament God is one that paints the wrong picture, and then the answers to the Qs it raises can be long-winded and unsatisfying.

Comment: Yes, paradoxes do arise if you read the OT only in view of the NT.  You were taught wrong, very wrong, but many others have been also.  The solution is simple:  read the OT first, then read the NT, with the OT in view.  Unfortunately modern preachers tell their followers to do exactly the opposite, they say if you read the OT first you'll end up hopelessly confused.  You won't.

Answer (score 0):

In Leviticus 24, Moses was addressing the audience of the Israelites. They were supposed to be a holy nation chosen by God. Further, the law was specifically about blasphemy.

In Mathew 5, Jesus was addressing not just the Jews but also the gentiles. Further, it wasn't about blasphemy. In fact, Jesus pointed out in
Matthew 12:31

> And so I tell you, every kind of sin and slander can be forgiven, but blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven.

Leviticus 24 and Mathew 5 were about different audiences and different kinds of sins. They are not exactly comparable.

Comment: So why shouldn't Leviticus 24 be no longer valid?

Comment: I'm not a Jew, so it is not valid to me. But it may still be valid to some group of people somewhere in the world. I don't know.

Comment: Why is not valid for you? Based on what reason you wouldn't follow this rule?

Comment: ? Any response to my comment?

Comment: Sorry,  I have no more comments on this.

Comment: Somehow I knew it

Comment: I'll make the best comment I can make.  Ancient Israel was both Church and State, there was no division as gradually evolved over many centuries.  Today, most people would not want to merge Church and State, that would be considered a huge violation of individual rights.  So it is simply not possible to enforce Leviticus 24 today, because of our modern society.  But that doesn't change the fact that it was valid back then, in Old Testament Israel.  And the basic principle remains:  Blasphemy against God is a very bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The penalty of death still stands under the New Covenant. It still stands since Christ burst onto the scene (as promised and prophesied since Gen3) at approx. 4BC

The penalty of sin is death.

Now though, through Jesus, we have opportunity that the OT looked forward to, but never experienced in it's fulness. (Abraham was blessed with *seeing* with the mind of course, not the eyes)

> Your father Abraham rejoiced as he looked forward to my coming. He saw it and was glad.” John 8:56

Now in Christ we have grace and forgiveness, not by the law, but by the perfect sacrifice of Jesus - a man without sin.

If one chooses to reject this kind offer, eternal death awaits them. But this eternal death is only after the resurrection - a facility God has arranged so that all men may be included in His offer of grace in Christ.

Now, the whole passage you quote from Mat 5 is about the kingdom of God. This is a totally new paradigm that far surpasses the old one of constant animal sacrifice to make good with God for a little while - a day, a month, a year - whatever the instruction was.

Now, we have one perfect sacrifice for all time and all men and perhaps even the heavenly realm also.

> But when this priest had offered for all time one sacrifice for sins, he sat down at the right hand of God. Heb 10:12

Yes, Jesus sitting at *God's right hand* gives a clue about who Jesus is, and who he is not. The writers of the NT were not crazy or ignorant about these matters - most of them were well-schooled by their master Jesus and inspired by Jesus' God, through His spirit. They knew perfectly well Jesus was not God, but His beloved son and servant.

Summary.

The God of the OT is the same God who fathered Jesus through Mary. Jesus came to reveal Him in ways not previously understood as the law was the *tutor* to bring us to Christ.

> so that the Law has become our trainer unto Christ, so that we might be justified by faith. Gal 3:24 BLB or *guardian* NIV, *teacher* CEV

Christ now has the goods to allow the way of forgiveness to stand unopposed. His victory over evil and death is sufficient to stand down the death penalty - but **only if we come to God in Jesus' name**.

Comment: So in simple words, Jesus did change the rules according to which you can be saved? If God of the OT is the same of the NT than he invalidated what he prescribed in Leviticus 24 since I don't see any Christian stoning people because of blasphemy

Comment: No, There was no salvation under anything before Jesus! OC was just a *type* which was very physically oriented. Jesus does God's will, he's making the old redundant through his sacrifice. God hasn't changed - just the way He administers His grace by the giving of His spirit which was not given before.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. Even though I understand what you say and I partially I agree I could go on making questions about this. I hope I didn't come out as rude. :)

Comment: :) yep there are lot's of questions! Due to some weird ideas that have firm roots in tradition but not in scripture, there is much confusion. Often the language about God and His plan has many unintended meanings to those with pre-determined ideas and theologies. Only with questions can this be sorted thru...

Comment: The thing for me is that even though I am a believer I am also very skeptic especially when talking about facts which are supposedly historical. Since reality cannot be altered, either those biblical passages are historically true or false. In such cases I wanna dig down to find out what it is correct... this was the reason for my question :)

Comment: Which is why I gave you a +1, it's a fair and reasonable Q. The *truth* was changed a few 100 yrs after the church started. There is no trinity in the writings, it is fabricated and unsupported except for a few poorly interpreted verses, and an ignoring of all those against this new gospel and the man Jesus who never said he was God and in Rev *still has a God*.

Comment: You have to understand and allow for the fact that we live in a different world today.  Ancient Israel was both Church AND State, and modern America is far from that.  If you can't or won't wrap your head around that, you will forever be hopelessly confused about stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Clear contradiction;

This has nothing to do about different audiences or civil and religious laws these are merely distractions/ excuses.  Jesus says - Matthew 5:17-19 "17 Think not that I came to destroy the law or the prophets: I came not to destroy, but to fulfil. 18 For verily I say unto you, ***Till heaven and earth pass away, one jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass away from the law***, till all things be accomplished. 19 Whosoever therefore shall break one of these least commandments, and shall teach men so, shall be called least in the kingdom of heaven: but whosoever shall do and teach them, he shall be called great in the kingdom of heaven." -   ***until the end of time*** not until Jesus resurrection/ ascension etc…

Exodus 20:7 “You shall not misuse the name of the Lord your God, for the Lord will not hold anyone guiltless who misuses his name

***Paul changes the Law***;
Romans 9:16 - 16 It does not, therefore, depend on human desire or effort, but on God’s mercy.

Acts 13:39 "Through him everyone who believes is set free from every sin, a justification you were not able to obtain under the law of Moses

Romans 3:20
20 Therefore no one will be declared righteous in God’s sight by the works of the law; rather, through the law we become conscious of our sin.

Galatians 2:16 16 know that a person is not justified by the works of the law, but by faith in Jesus Christ.

Ephesians 2:15 by abolishing in His flesh the law of commandments and decrees. He did this to create in Himself one new man out of the two, thus making peace

Galatians 3:19 Why then was the law given? It was added because of transgressions, until the arrival of ***the seed*** to whom the promise referred. It was administered through angels by a mediator. - Jesus arrived and gave the same Law as before.

I could mention so many verses could write a book, but I will end with the below;

There is ***only 1 teacher*** - Matthew 23:8–12 8 But you are not to be called rabbi, for you have one teacher, and you are all brothers. 9 And call no man your father on earth, for you have one Father, who is in heaven. 10 Neither be called instructors, for you have one instructor, the Christ. 11 The greatest among you shall be your servant. 12 ***Whoever exalts himself will be humbled***, and whoever humbles himself will be exalted.

Paul;2 Timothy 1:11 - 11 And of this gospel I was appointed a herald and an apostle and a teacher.

Comment: Does "*Paul changes the Law*" mean that *you* believe the human Paul had the power to change God's law? Or that Paul *believed* that he had the power? Or that some people *today* believe that Paul had the power? Or that (from an atheistic view) Paul created new laws that were accepted by the early Christians?

Comment: @RayButterworth from text evidence (on many points) Pauls appears to have changed Jesus teachings and teachings of the prophets (manipulated the text and created his own laws).  This can also be seen in his use of OT but changing the meaning such as;  Roman 11:26: And so all Israel will be saved, as it is written: “The Deliverer will ***come from Zion***; He will ***remove godlessness from Jacob***.
Isaiah 59:20-21: “The Redeemer will ***come to*** Zion, to those in ***Jacob who repent*** of their sins,” declares the LORD.